# Selenium drag and dropping a JQuery element

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use Selenium's Action class to drag and drop a source element that is inside a JQuery nested sortable list to another element.  I have used the standard dragAndDrop method as well as broken it down to clickAndHold, moveToElement, and release but neither of those work.  I even tried using the source elements inner child to drag but the result is the same.

When I run the script the test comes back as passed so I know the elements are being found and the selectors are valid.  Selenium thinks the drag and drop operation worked but when I observe the test, I see no action what so ever.  I have confirmed with a few developers that I am indeed targeting the right source element to drag as far as the DOM is concerned.

**EDIT:** I have tried using the build() method before performing the action and even slowed down the test by sleeping the thread but the result is the same.

**EDIT 2:** I have also added the destination where the source is needed to be dropped into.  I should also mention the source element (on drag event) has a sortable-ghost object created and THAT object what is copied into the destination element container when a user manually drags it into the destination element.

This is the destination container I am trying to drag to.

```
<div class="schedDayItem anytimeSection" data-bind="nestedSortable: { 
    foreach: AutoEvents, options: { animation: 600, group: 
   'autoevents', scroll: true, onStart: EnableDragging, onEnd: 
    DisableDragging } }" style="min-height: 60px; position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;"></div>
```

Here is the parent of the element I want to drag.  It is the JQuery nested sortable list:

```
<div class="listDayItem anytimeSection" style="font-size: 14px;" 
    data-bind="nestedSortable: { foreach: EventList, options: { animation:
    600, group: { name: 'draggbleevents', pull: 'clone', put: false }, 
    onEnd: $root.GetBaseEvents, sort: false } }">
```

And here is the source element I am trying to move, the nested sortables direct child:

```
<div class="draggableEventItem pointer" style="margin: 3px 0; border-
    radius: 3px;">
```

And just for completeness, the inner child of the source element I want to move:

```
<div id="container" data-bind="class: EventType, style: { backgroundColor: 
    EventBackground }" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid 
    #AAA; padding: 4px 0; border-radius: 3px;" class="border-left-red">
```

Here is what I am trying to do in code:

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    //eventAlert is the element I am trying to move.
    //eventName is a string I am using to find the right element in the JQuery List.  One of the source elements inner children provide this string.

    List<WebElement>list = driver.findElements(eventAlert);
    for(WebElement we : list){
        if(we.getText().contains(eventName)){
            action.dragAndDrop(we, driver.findElement(eventElementTarget)).perform();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't figure out how to get dragAndDrop method working in this particular problem, I did find a way around it by using the push action in Javascript.  I'll continue experimenting to see if maybe a nested sortable jQuery list is buggy with selenium but for now, this workaround is solid.

Below I create a list as I did before but this time use a counter as an iteration device.  I am searching AutoSequenceItems and pushing them to the Event list which is my destination container.  This method requires knowing the actual Javascript of the site but if working along side developers, it shouldn't be a problem in most cases.  This is just an example of a possible workaround, others will not have AutoSequenceItems and such in their site.

```
    List<WebElement>list = driver.findElements(eventListItem);
    int counter = 0;
    for(WebElement we : list){
        if(we.getText().contains(eventName)){
            js.executeScript("return AutonEdit.Main.AutoSequenceItems()[0]"
                    + ".AutoEvents.push(AutoEdit.Main.EventList()[" + counter +"]);");
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the build() method before the perform() method

```
action.dragAndDrop(we, driver.findElement(eventElementTarget)).build().perform();
```

I tried the following test for a jquery example that drop and drags from one element to a different element, not sure this would help:

```
@Test
public void testDropAndDrag() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html");
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement card1 = driver.findElement(By.id("card1"));
    WebElement card1Drop = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-droppable"));
    act.dragAndDrop(card1,card1Drop).perform();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

**Update**
I was able to reproduce the condition you were experiencing using the example at this site: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

If you take a look at the source, I was grabbing the  id to get the list of

elements, which would worked but in the loop it would run but not do anything.  Must be something with getting a list of elements within jquery.

I changed the list to grab all the

elements instead, and it worked.  Here is the updated test example:

```
@Test
public void testDropAndDrag() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists");

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe.demo-frame"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
    List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul > li.ui-state-default"));
    WebElement list2 = driver.findElement(By.id("sortable2"));
    for(WebElement item : list1){
        System.out.println(item.getText());
        if(item.getText().equals("Item 1")){
            System.out.println(item.getText());
            act.dragAndDrop(item,list2).perform();
            break;
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added that.  I have tried to use the build method but the result was the same.

Comment: Are you able to post the url that your testing?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I am dealing with some proprietary code so even the elements I posted had a few detail names changed.  I can say though there are other places in the site I have tested drag and drop and it has worked fine, but those pages and elements are Javascript where this one is a bit more sophisticated with JQuery.

Comment: I edited my Answer, not sure that will help.  It could be something in your loop?

Comment: You raised a good point though, I didn't check the loop but I tried it just now using direct element source/destination locators and forgo the loop completely and still get the same result.  I also put your code into a dummy test inside my environment to make sure its not something environmental and it works just fine.

Comment: Joe, another update, take a look at how the list (we) is getting the listed items.

Comment: I took a look at that if maybe the container parent needs to be targeted.  In the DOM I am working with I only have the container with no other child elements like the page you mentioned.  I went ahead and targeted 3 parents up just to see if there was a change in behavior but nothing so far.  I also added the destination to my original post

Comment: What does your code for the eventAlert web element look like?

Comment: By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'draggableEventItem')]"); then I just reference this with the driver find element method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149256/discussion-between-smit9234-and-joe-chavis).